# Which is quicker in the below two type mysql table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

i have 100000 value stored in Mysql , and i hesitated between two index choice

first way is the normal one , with ID auto increment

[image]

and the second one is separate 100000 value into 200 auto increment ID , and each ID has 500 Sub_ID ,so 200x500=100000

[image]

Which one would be quicker ? the first is the traditional

`select value from table where ID = xxx`

and the second one is

`select value from table where ID = xxx and sub_ID = xxx`

cause the first one will loop every cell, but second one just loop in 200 ID , and then loop in 500 Sub_ID , so in theory , the second one would be better , right?

Comment: Don't hesitate. In these cases, it's always quicker and more reliable to just try both alternatives, rather than ask us.

Comment: well, the mysql deployment  is costly , and if not met , to re-split or re-combine is a trouble, what is more, i want to know deep mechanism of index, it is also a good turn to provide inspiration to who meets the same problem

Comment: Yes. All that's good. But that wasn't your question.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key one is faster. Otherwise you are making multiple index scans. Unless you have values over 1 000 000 000 000 I wouldn't bother with "optimizing" primary keys.

Also if you only want to get the value and not only the ID, you can create a composite index of the ID and the Value which will be the fastest option as the value will be included in the index and you won't even be hitting the table with your query.